# python app works locally but gives error in docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, scikit-learn

I'm running my app locally in localhost:80 and I get proper results.
Then I build a docker image and run it and it gives the following error (running docker in attached mode):

I'm using Windows 10.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./main.py", line 90, in scan
    result = sig_analyzer(signature=text)
  File "./sig_analyze.py", line 65, in sig_analyzer
    line_classes, probsA = classify.line_predict(signature)
  File "./classify.py", line 31, in line_predict
    classes = mlp.predict(feats)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py", line 643, in predict
    predicted_probabilitiy = self.predict_proba(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py", line 692, in predict_proba
    for i in range(n_jobs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 996, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 899, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 517, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
sklearn.externals.joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.
```

Why does it work locally but not in a container? Why would my OS kill such a process?

I should clarify that a previous version of the same app was working just fine. The difference is that now I'm using a function (a bagging classifier from sklearn) that executes among a number of threads. The number of threads is not the issue (eg. I run with only 2 and with as many as they are available).

Does docker need specific configuration to  run multiple threads?

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: have you installed `python3-dev`? It is a requirement for uWSGI

Comment: Hi Anderson K . How do I check if I meet those requirements?
I imagine I do because previous versions of this app worked just fine, locally or  in docker.